# Full Text Search or String Search in Google App Engine over Entities for displaying Instant results

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am working on feature like google instant. It is build on Google AppEngine Python 2.7.

For that i need to fetch  entities  From datastore.

Each entity has two  attributes.  (nemo,company_name)  both String Type.

The model is based on
http://code.google.com/p/gae-text-search/  for allowing  full text search.

The model class is

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
import tzsearch
class Items(tzsearch.SearchableModel):
    nemo=db.StringProperty()
    company_name=db.StringProperty()
```

But when i run

```
query='any query string'
from models.models import Items
query_obj=Items.all().search(query)
```

The above code works fine for query of length greater than 2 and returns only the matching entities.
But for query of length 1 and 2  returns  all the entities.

Making the response very slow.

I am really stuck here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Now that AppEngine [supports Full Text Search](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview) the gae-text-search project should be considered deprecated.

Comment: I am new too Google app engine ... Can you Please give me a sample code how to use it?

Comment: I saw this http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/search/python/search_demo.py  but how to implement similar for  the model i am using?

Comment: @RaviSimon full text search it's not that simple to just give you an example.. you have to go through documentation and understand how it works, especially if you're new to Google App Engine..

Comment: @Lipis Maybe you should add FTS to gaeinit

Comment: @ShayErlichmen thanks for the suggestion.. I didn't play with it yet, but FTS is really project specific, and gae-init covers the very basic stuff that most of the WebApps going to need.. Also is for more advanced users, so if someone needs FTS they should be able to include it.. Give it a spin.. and since I didn't have time to document all the weird conventions you can send a feedback and I'll get back to you with details...